# JQuery datepicker function not recognized or not functioning on new project

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been going down some rabbit holes trying to get date picker to work.  I used it a year ago on an existing project without issue, but now I seem to have issue with displaying it or using a JQuery function for it.  I have the following files at the top of my HTML code.

```
    <!-- Bootstrap Library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- JQuery library -->
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sidebar.js"></script>
    <script src="thisweek.js"></script>
```

Then further down I have the calls for the datepicker:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">Date</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend" id="addJobDate">                               
                <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addJobDate">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are the JQuery statements for the datepicker in the this week.js file.

```
$('#addJobDate').datepicker({ format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'});

// database calls

$('#pushJobDB').on("click", function() {
    var currentDate = $('#addJobDate').datepicker('getDate').val();     
    var cost = $('#cost').val();
```

In the javascript console I get the error:

TypeError: $('#addJobDate').datepicker is not a function.  It doesn't matter whether I have the format section or not, it doesn't seem to be recognized. Do you know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Judging from your includes I'd say you probably want `.datetimepicker`, not `.datepicker`

Comment: I changed it to datetimepicker and got a different error:  undefined is not an object.  Do I really need all the moment.js, datetimepicker.mins.js stuff on my includes?

Comment: It's hard to say what you need without seeing all your code. You'll need to use developer tools to figure out that error, but I wouldn't think it's coming from what you have unless `datetimepicker` is returning undefined.

Comment: define what you mean by 'seeing all your code?' All of the js stuff is inside $(document).ready(function() { });  The HTML stuff has all of the information in it.  There aren't any other css, or js files in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `css` and `js` for `bootstrap-datepicker` as below insted of `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js`

```js
$('#addJobDate').datepicker({ format: 'dd-M-yyyy'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">Date</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend" id="addJobDate">                               
                <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="addJobDate">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```